# Cannot cast Application

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-manifest

I'm implementing Analytics v.4 into my app. 
And I have a problem getting tracker.

Here's the code

```
public class FactsActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);

    Tracker t = ((Analytics) getApplication()).getTracker(
            Analytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);        
    t.setScreenName("OLOLO");       
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

I get an error for the line

```
 Tracker t = ((Analytics) getApplication()).getTracker(Analytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

It is: "**Inconvertible types: cannot cast 'android.app.Application' to 'com.tomtom.facts.Analytics**'

I've been looking for the resolution here and as I see, I should modify my AndroidManifest.xml to include "android:name=..." into "application" tag. But I can't do it. It brakes with error: '**com.tomtom.facts.Analytics'is not assignable to 'android.app.Application'**.

Please help! I'm totally stuck.

Here's Analytics class

```
public class Analytics extends Activity {

public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER,
    GLOBAL_TRACKER,
    E_COMMERCE_TRACKER,
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {

    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker("UA-*******-1")
                : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
                : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

}

Comment: I think you may use the api *incorrectly*... u r trying to let `Analysis` be a `Application`, but it **can't** be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right line would be:

```
Tracker t = (Tracker) getApplication().getTracker(Analytics.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
```

The problem probably is that you put the parentheses in the wrong place. You tried to cast the object returned by `getApplication()`.
and additionally that you probably have to cast to `Tracker` instead of `Analytics`

Comment: It returns an error: **cannot resolve method getTracker(...**

Comment: getTracker method is set up in Analitics class as syncronized, but it can't be used from another class. What should I do?